# Remember the high score in 2 ViewControllers in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults, viewcontroller

Iv'e got 2 ViewControllers, In the first one the user get the points and the high score label.
In the second ViewController, the code calculates if the user has broke the old high score, if yes - it changes, of course. BUT! when I quit the app and start playing again, the high score label show my **last score** and not the highest score.
Here is my code:

First ViewController:

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.synchronize()
highScore.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: oldScore)
```

Second ViewController:

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if score > oldScore {
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "oldScore")
    defaults.synchronize()
    var money = defaults.valueForKey("oldScore") as! Int
    oldScore = money
} else {
    defaults.setInteger(oldScore, forKey: "oldScore")
    defaults.synchronize()
    var money = defaults.valueForKey("oldScore") as! Int
    oldScore = money
}
```

I also got `var oldScore = Int()` in the view controller code but outside the class of the view controller.

In addition, I have a "Switch" button that starts with state of "ON". But sometimes me/the user want to change it to off, how can I save it to be the user's choice after I quit the app and relaunch?

Comment: it seems that the `else` branch is completely useless. If there is no higher score the old value on disk doesn't need to be changed. It's also not necessary – nor recommended – to read the value back just after writing it.

Comment: @vadian ok, I deleted the `else` code. But it still doesn't change - it shows me my **last score** and not the high score.

Comment: delete the line `var money = defaults.valueForKey("oldScore") as! Int` and change the next line to `oldScore = score` in the `if` branch

Comment: @vadian I did it and still - it shows me my **last score** instead of the high score

Comment: Debug and make sure, it is going inside your "if" code.. i.e you are calculating the "score" and it is greater than your "oldscore". You can "println" to check

Comment: In the first view controller no value is read from user defaults. Replace the `synchronize` line with `let oldScore = defaults.integerForKey("oldScore")`

Comment: @Munahil I tried to println it, for some reason, everytime I quit and relaunch - "oldScore" is set to 0, but the high score label shows the last score.
vadian Still doesn't work..

Comment: where does the last score come from?

Comment: @vadian last score isn't a variable, let's say i played a game and got 20 score. now I played a new game and scored 15. so my last score is 15 and this is what the high score label show

Comment: By using this "var oldScore = Int() ", you are resetting the old score again

Comment: @Munahil How do I fix it?

Comment: I have posted an answer, see if it fixes it. If it doesn't let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if `NSUserDefault` for `oldScore` is set. If it is not set only then initialise the `oldScore`, otherwise don't. Just fetch the value of oldScore and compare it with the new score and set the value accordingly

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(oldScore) == nil) {
    oldScore = Int()
}
```

In your Second View Controller, first of all put `NSUserDefault's oldScore`'s value into a variable and then check if it is equal to your `Score`. If it is only then set it like this :

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var oldScoreCheck = defaults.valueForKey("oldScore") as! Int
if score > oldScoreCheck {
   defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "oldScore")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: I have got a lot of mess because of all the answers, can you write please what I need to write in the first view controller, seconds view controller & outside of them?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please make further changes in your code accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! it works! thank you! Can you explain how it worked?

Comment: In first view controller, it will only initialise it if  iNSUserDefault is not set otherwise it wont. And in the second view controller it will get the value from NSUserDefault and then compare it

Comment: Great! now I get it, thanks! Do you know how to solve the "switch" problem? (its in the end of the question)

Answer (score 0):

In your first view controller make the following change.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if defaults.integerForKey("oldScore") != nil
{
   highScore.text = defaults.integerForKey("oldScore")
}
else
{
   highScore.text = 0
}
```

There might be some changes required dependent on the variable type of highScore.
Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According Apple's documentation you should register all default values before using them.

- In AppDelegate in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add this code to register the key `oldScore` to have a reliable default value. A key `switchState` is also registered for the mentioned "Switch" button.

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let defaultValues = ["oldScore" : 0, "switchState" : "ON"]
  defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
  ```
- In the first view controller retrieve the high score value. If no value has been ever written to disk, the registered default value (0) is taken. You could read the value for the "Switch" button respectively.

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let oldScore = defaults.integerForKey("oldScore")
  let buttonState = defaults.stringForKey("switchState")
  highScore.text = "\(oldScore)"
  ```
- In the second view controller save the high score if changed

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let oldScore = defaults.integerForKey("oldScore")
  if score > oldScore {
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "oldScore")
    defaults.synchronize()
    oldScore = score
  }
  ```